# How to transfer files over HTTP?

Tags: http, webdav, file-transfer

I'm looking for a solution that enables file transfer over HTTP. The need arises because I'm connecting between computers that are behind a firewall that allows only HTTP communication over ports 80 and 443.

I've been suggested WebDAV as it is a ready solution and all my clients need to do is set up a network drive to access the files.
What other solutions are there for transferring files over HTTP?
Base64 encoding means I have to implement a client **and** a server that could be a source of bugs in the system.

*Edit:* what's good about the WebDAV solution, is that it gives the clients an environment they already know - network shares. Any way to simulate this (or give them another environment that's familiar) for ease of use. I come onto this project with the assumption that my clients are very dumb and I really don't want complaints about difficulty of use.

Comment: You can proxy your connection over ssh or openvpn. Both work on port 80 if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Why not using an already made client like "apache" or "tomcat" or any other server where yoy can "deploy" your file. Then you can implement some kind of User Interface (client) to "download" the files.

Server: Tomcat, Apache any other server that can serve the files

Client: You can implement some UI to download the files.

Comment: +1 When using a web server, only a browser is needed at client side. Downloading files only requires allowing access to the directory that contains the files. For uploading, you need a form for selecting the file with Browse button, and a script that receives the file.

Comment: Yes, that's what i mean with "implement some UI" :-)